# How to populate a multimap in Dart

Tags: dart

I'm using a MultiMap from the [quiver](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.collection/Multimap-class.html) package. I'm trying to populate the map with 2 lists like I would with  an ordinary map:

```
final keys = myMap.keys.toList();
final values = myMap.values.toList();

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      map[values[i]] = itemSpit[I];
    }
```

However the for loop doesn't compile: value

`The operator '[]=' isn't defined for the type 'Multimap<dynamic, dynamic>'.`

How can I add the lists to the multimap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart has two versions of the square brackets operator; one for reading (`operator []`) and one for writing (`operator []=`). `Multimap` providers `operator []` but does *not* provide `operator []=`.  Presumably this is because it would be unclear to readers whether `multimap[key] = value` intends to add a new value or to replace the existing values.

Instead, `Multimap` provides [`add`](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.collection/Multimap/add.html) and [`addValues`](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.collection/Multimap/addValues.html) methods for adding values. (Replacing requires explicitly calling [`removeAll`](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.collection/Multimap/removeAll.html) first.)